# Changing color JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, colors

My problem is: I have three elements on a list, and I have to keep changing the text color when the mouse is hover.

So I am building 3 different functions, because the colors are different.

What I did is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var links  = document.getElementsByClassName("menuitems");
 function firsthover()
{
   links[0].style.color = "rgb(204, 0, 0)"; /*this is for avoiding setInterval delay*/

     setInterval(function(){
     if(links[0].style.color == "rgb(204, 0, 0)")
     { 
     links[0].style.color = "rgb(235, 153, 153)";
     }

     if(links[0].style.color == "rgb(235, 153, 153)")
     {
     links[0].style.color = "rgb(204, 0, 0)";
     }

    },1150);
}
 </script>
```

The problem is: it changes the color just once.

I tried to use hexadecimal color too, just doesn't work.

Please be patient, I am still a novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a small logical flaw. The color does change, but it changes back right away.

If the first `if` statement evaluates as true and the color is set to `rgb(235, 153, 153)` the second `if` statement happens to be true as well, and gets checked right after the change. The color then changes back to the other rgb value.

Using `else if` instead of two separate statements fixes this. Alternatively you could place a `return` in the first if statement to prevent the second from being executed after the successful change.

```
if(links[0].style.color == "rgb(204, 0, 0)")
{ 
    links[0].style.color = "rgb(235, 153, 153)";
}
else if(links[0].style.color == "rgb(235, 153, 153)")
{
    links[0].style.color = "rgb(204, 0, 0)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS.

Put the code below inside your `<head>` tag.

```
<style type="text/css">

.menuitems {
  color: rgb(204, 0, 0);
}

.menuitems:hover {
  color: rgb(235, 153, 153);
}

</style>
```

It works perfectly well.

---

You can also use different colors for different items by using different classes.

Define a base class for `menuitems`, that will be the base color of them. Then add a different class for each color you would like to use.

Your CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

.menuitems { /* base color */
  color: rgb(204, 0, 0);
}

.menuitems:hover { /* base hover color */
  color: rgb(235, 153, 153);
}

.menuitem-red:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
}

.menuitem-green:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 255, 0) !important;
}

.menuitem-blue:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 255) !important;
}

</style>
```

Your HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="menuitem">Menu item base</li>
  <li class="menuitem menuitem-red">Menu item red</li>
  <li class="menuitem menuitem-green">Menu item green</li>
  <li class="menuitem menuitem-blue">Menu item blue</li>
</ul>
```

The name of classes I used and the colors are for sample purposes. Feel free to use the ones you think that fits better for your design.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didnt' explay it in the right way. When the mouse is hover the color has to keep changing. That's why i am using js. Thank you for the answer